# AWS IOT Policy - limited to specified ClientID

Tags: aws-iot, aws-iot-core

I have created the following policy below which is to limit ClientID connections allowed for MQTT clients. It is supposed to limit to one hardcoded ClientID "test" and one CLientID that is the name of the AWS Thing.  Using the name of the AWS Thing works, but my hardcoded "test" ClientId does not work?

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": "iot:Connect",
      "Resource": "*",
      "Condition": {
        "Bool": {
          "iot:Connection.Thing.IsAttached": [
            "true"
          ]
        },
        "ForAnyValue:StringEquals": {
          "iot:ClientId": [
            "test",
            "${iot:Connection.Thing.ThingName}"
          ]
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": "iot:Publish",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:iot:us-east-1:xxx:topic/$aws/things/${iot:Connection.Thing.ThingName}/*"
    },
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": "iot:Subscribe",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:iot:us-east-1:xxx:topicfilter/$aws/things/${iot:Connection.Thing.ThingName}/*"
    },
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": "iot:Receive",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:iot:us-east-1:xxx:topic/$aws/things/${iot:Connection.Thing.ThingName}/*"
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you have the `"iot:Connection.Thing.IsAttached": ["true"]` set, I believe a Thing with the name of `test` needs to be registered in the Thing Registry with the principal attached to it.

Comment: I thought "iot:Connection.Thing.IsAttached" does a look by the cert be used, but you may be right!

Comment: Yeah cert attached to a Thing in the Registry